# prefuse: useful layout for directed mostly-acyclic graph?

Tags: java, prefuse

I have a moderately complex graph (500-1000 nodes) representing function calls in a program, so it is almost completely acyclic, and mostly tree-like (e.g. occasionally there are multiple paths from one subroutine to another, but usually not). I would like to visualize it.

My first thought was to use [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/gallery/), and within an hour I got something running based on the examples. But it uses ForceDirectedLayout, which visually looks like a mess for this size graph, and it slows down my PC.

Are there other useful Prefuse layouts for this kind of graph?